# Paying for gas on behalf of users?

Tags: contract-design, gas, dapps, accounts, gas-refund

I'm exploring ways to enable contracts/dApp owners to pay for gas on behalf of users.

I know contact abstraction should enable this eventually, and the first step has been done with [EIP208](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/pull/208) which introduces NULL_SENDER, but I'm interested in what can be done now.

From what I've seen here on StackEchange and elsewhere, it all comes down to two options:

**1. Refund users after they perform a transaction**

This is actually not an option :) because I want users not to touch ETH, they don't even need to know that ETH exists.

**2. Collect signed TXs/messages from users and forward them to the blockchain (and pay for gas, of course)**

This is a valid solution, but the big problem is that users need to *trust* the dApp owner/message handler to forward their messages. I've stumbled upon uPort's [meta transactions](https://medium.com/uport/making-uport-smart-contracts-smarter-part-3-fixing-user-experience-with-meta-transactions-105209ed43e0) and their concept of multiple relayers is somehow appealing, but it's not clear how are relayers incentivized to forward TXs/messages and pay for gas? I've send uPort team a message, waiting for the answer... Ethereum Alarm Clock is a great project and something similar can be also implemented for the problem I'm talking about, but there are no guarantees that TXs will be executed.

Regarding all of this, I have two questions:

1. Is there any way/idea to do this forwarding in a trustless way now, when we still don't have account abstraction)?
2. Can anyone explain how this will work when account abstraction gets implemented?

Thanks! :)

Comment: what about just asking user for parameters and sending all transactions with a unique account (your dapp account), then you can have user specific balances, information, etc in a smart contract.